# Use Google Tasks in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, lightning, google-tasks

I'm using the GDataProvider along with Lightning to access my Google Calendar from Thunderbird. However I'd also like to have access to my Google Tasks as well. Does anybody know if this is possible at present?

The [GDataProvider wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Calendar:GDATA_Provider) suggests that they will support this eventually (they've been stuck waiting for a Tasks API), but I'm wondering if anybody has managed to get this working any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure how it'd be possible to get your task data without the API implemented. I'd love someone to prove me wrong though.

Comment: GDataProvider Wiki moved to https://github.com/kewisch/gdata-provider/wiki

Answer (score 3):

One interesting workaround for this problem, whilst we're stuck waiting for tasks API, is to use Bryan Clark's [Google Calendar Tab](http://clarkbw.net/blog/2009/11/23/google-calendar-in-thunderbird-tabs/). As long as you have your tasks displayed on your Google calendar, you will then have access to them from Thunderbird too.

Obviously this isn't as good as native integration into Thunderbird via an API, but its the best I've managed so far.

Comment: This is good, but the problem is that it opens the same page as google calendar, and if you already have sidebar with lighning calendar and tasks open, it is visually cluttered.

Answer (score 3):

Google has released the [Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/tasks/overview) in May 2011 ([getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/tasks/get_started)). The [GDATA Provider issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=493389) was resolved in 3.8.

Comment: The bug was closed 9 years ago.

Comment: @Rubén updated. You can remove your downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to directly sync, one problem being that 'Google Tasks' are far simpler than 'Thunderbird Tasks'. Howerver, "Google Tasks Sync 0.3.1" is a currently working addon that pops up in the Task daily pane to the right of the calendar and email (when daily pane view is active) and presents the Google Task system nested neatly there. It's not a web browser view of Google's own 'Tasks' window, but a proper, native add-on, consistent with Google's task system and synced with it. It means that the very good T'bird task management is bypassed, and there is an initial signing in process the first time that you use it, but other that that, it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the google tasks page itself at: https://mail.google.com/tasks/ig?pli=1

Is there a thunderbird extension that would allow you to display the contents of that url in the sidebar?  If so, that is all you would need.  No need for Google's API.